# How to instantiate an object out of a template of a class (String)

Tags: java

i want to make a webpage where people can register, build their own AI on the Ultimatum-Game as a Java Class and compete each other. The can edit their Class in a textarea, which get stored in a database.

My problem is now getting an object from a class that is just a String yet.
I hope someone can help me.
best regards

test.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>random</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test2.jsp" method="post"> 
   <div>  
      <label for="text">Klasse</label>
         <textarea id="text" name="text" cols="100" rows="50">
 public class test {
    String teststring;
    public test() {
        this.teststring ="Hallo";
    }
}

    </textarea>     
      <input type="submit" value="Senden" />
   </div> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

test2.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>random</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test2.jsp" method="post"> 
   <div>  
      <label for="text">Klasse</label>
         <textarea id="text" name="text" cols="100" rows="50">
 public class test {
    String teststring;
    public test() {
        this.teststring ="Hallo";
    }
}

    </textarea>     
      <input type="submit" value="Senden" />
   </div> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are basically asking for a compiler, which is a big ask.  Maybe you can rethink your design.  Why not have a generic object, or set of objects, which your users can create via a command pattern?